# VS - how to set a general setting to all app's instances?

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, service, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I'm trying to set a general password to my app, which means every user will have the same password to enter.

I've tried using the Project's settings - [Application.Current.Setting.Default.settingName] for the password - but then each user [in his own installed app on his PC] would have his own password, and that's not what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to set a 'general' setting to all app's instances? My project uses VSTS as well, if there's an option from there.

(I see there's a service called 'Web settings', is that it? If so, would you give me an usage example?)

Thanks!

Comment: How do you use that password? How do you deploy your app?

Comment: The password is stored in my Project's settings, as said above :)

Answer (score 1):

The good way is that you can store password (can be encrypted) in the configuration file, such as app.config, web.config, then read it from configuration file before use it.

You may replace the password before deploy your app through [Replace Token](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) step (VSTS build/release)

Comment: Would that make the password an overall password to all users? If the config file is individual per user it won't help me make it overall, am I wrong?

Comment: @Yair Why the config file is individual per user? How do you do it? You can provide the detail scenario (project type, how to use password, how to deploy app).